# Diferencia entre SMTP y SMTP relay

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

Queria consultarles, cual es la diferencia entre SMTP y SMTP relay. Y como se deberia implementar este ultimo en .net.

Este es mi codigo de SMTP

```html
 String _fromAdress = "pepe";
                String _smtpserver = "Smtp.Gmail.com";

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(_smtpserver);
                mail.From = new MailAddress(_fromAdress);
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Cuenta de mail", "CLAVE");

                string from="";
                string to="";
                string subject="";
                try {

                         await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                    var nombre = provider.Contents[0].Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.ToString();
                    string nombrearchivo = nombre;

                    var VARfrom = provider.Contents[1].ReadAsStringAsync();
                        from = VARfrom.Result.ToString();

                        var VARto = provider.Contents[2].ReadAsStringAsync();
                        to = VARto.Result.ToString();

                        var VARasunto = provider.Contents[3].ReadAsStringAsync();
                        subject = VARasunto.Result.ToString();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }

                mail.To.Add(to);
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = "Cuerpo del mail";
                mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                SmtpServer.Port = Convert.ToInt32(587);
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                    data.Name = subject;


                
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                return Ok();
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En palabras simples, el servidor SMTP es el que envía el correo en tu caso smtp.gmail.com, un SMTP relay es un servidor SMTP que te sirve como puente entre tu cliente SMTP y tu servidor SMTP real.

Por ejemplo puedes tener una impresora (u otro dispositivo) que envía correos pero que su firmware no soporta el protocolo de seguridad TLS, en dado caso puedes configurar dentro de tu red una computadora como servidor SMTP que si soporte TLS, apuntas los parámetros de tu impresora a dicha computadora como su servidor SMTP y configuras la computadora para que retransmita los correos que reciba a smtp.gmail.com para que lleguen a su destinatario.

También puedes usar un SMTP relay cuando tu cliente SMTP tiene otras limitaciones para conectarse a un servidor SMTP real como es el tipo de autenticación; para mejorar el rendimiento de una aplicación usando un SMTP relay dentro de tu red en lugar de Internet, entre otras.

Existen muchos servidores SMTP que puedes configurar como SMTP relay por ejemplo [IIS de Windows Server](https://www.tectimes.net/tutorial-windows-server-configuracion-de-smtp-server-en-windows-server-2008-y-2008-r2/) u otros gratuitos como [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/).

**Nota:** Si tu pregunta es como programar un servidor SMTP para usarlo como mail relay te sugiero hacer una publicación nueva para dar congruencia a la pregunta y respuesta actual.

Comment: Muchas gracias, respondiste perfecto mi pregunta. Plantee mal la pregunta porque desconocía totalmente el tema. Saludos y gracias!